# Cannot delete "ghost" table from Power Pivot

Tags: excel, powerquery, powerpivot, datamodel

I have created many power queries and power pivot tables in my Excel file. After some time, I think the data structure may have gotten corrupted, because this is happening:

In Data Model, I have this Community_Membership table that cannot be deleted. It is the only table that has this behavior (all other tables were deleted successfully)

[image]

After that, I went to Power Query to delete all existing queries AND CONNECTIONS, so that the list is empty like below.
[image]

[image]

[image]

But this table remains un-deletable there after I have deleted all queries from queries list.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally recreated the file as follows:

- Make a new Excel file
- Copy all of the sheets
- Select all of the queries from the old file's query pane, hit copy
- Go to the new file's queries pane, hit paste
- Go into Query Editor and edit any names with conflicts or remove any redundant queries

The entire process takes about 10 minutes as I only had about 10 queries / sheets.

I suspect this happened because I created a query, added it to the data model then went back to Power Query and edit it (either its name or its content in some mysterious way). After that the link between PQ and PP is broken so that even after the original query is deleted, its clone in PP remains. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar situation after having renamed a query in Power Query : Power Pivot could see the new table under the new name, but the old table was still there in Power Pivot and could not be deleted.

Finally I came up with this solution :

1. Make sure there are no remaining relationships or measures in Power Pivot that refer to the table you want to delete.
2. Create a query in Power Query, having the same name as the table you want to delete. The content of the query does not matter. Make sure that the checkbox "load into the datamodel" is checked. As a result, the synchronization between Power Pivot and Power Query is restored.
3. Edit the query again and uncheck the checkbox. Now Power Pivot understands that we want to remove that table.
4. Now you can delete the query in Power Query.